# how can I dynamically pass data to the scipy.stats Levene's test function?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, anova

I'm trying to automate pretesting for one-way ANOVA. My data will vary in the number of treatments so I want to be able to pass them to the Levene's test dynamically.

This works:

```
from scipy.stats import levene

dat = [[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[2,3,4]]

print levene(dat[0],dat[1],dat[2])
```

This doesn't:

```
dat = [[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[2,3,4]]

print levene(dat)
```

Is there a way to pass data to the test dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack `dat` unsing the `*args`-syntax.

```
levene(*dat)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know! :-)